# How to add Mail template in newsletter_subscribe extension?

Tags: typo3, newsletter, typo3-10.x

I have an error when submitting the newsletter form.
[image]

I'm using the newsletter_subscribe extension for my TYPO3 v10 newsletter form. There is no field to add the template. I can only find a field labeled *Template path for mails*.
[image]

What is this for and how to solve the error?
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you override the templates and/or use a language which is not supported by the extension, you need to create language folder like it is done in the extension, see: https://github.com/Gregor-Agnes/newsletter_subscribe/tree/master/Resources/Private/Templates/Mail

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood. But here the default template is also not appearing.

Comment: What language do you use? In the extension there are only templates for de and en.

Comment: I'm using de. I got an error related to a view helper in this. I think this issue is due to the view helper. (https://prnt.sc/upvt26)